# Import trust cert using java keystore fails

Tags: java, swing, exception, keystore, pkcs#11

I am trying to import a trust cert into a smartcard with Keystore type PKCS11 using:

`ks.setEntry` 
`ks.setCertificateEntry`

and both fail with `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: trusted certificates may only be set by token initialization application`

How can I get past this?